# android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED - do not receive broadcast if boot completed by a phone call

Tags: android, android-intent, broadcastreceiver

I am using a broadcast receiver in my app, to display a photo on BOOT_COMPLETED. However, I noticed that if I receive a phone call on my phone, the photo is displayed in front of incoming phone call activity, so I can's see who is calling me and what is worse - can't answer the phone.

What is the best way to override this behavior?

Comment: Do you have intent filter check?

Comment: yes, but am not sure which specific filter should I use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could add another mechanism for listening to phone calls events, and if you detect that the phone is ringing (or the call was answered), you won't show the activity...

in any case, please don't show such things. no user likes popups go out of nowhere.

instead, use notifications to tell the user something has happened.

Comment: Don't worry, I do not have bad intentions with this app. Regarding the issue - is there any filter (or some other mechanism) to distinguish if the broadcast has been sent due to human interaction or not?

Comment: i don't understand. humans aren't supposed to send bootup-intents... it is done after the device has finished booting up (and loading some apps, like the launcher)...

Comment: few hours later ... you are correct - the right action was supposed to be ACTION_SCREEN_ON but the problem still existed on incoming call... solved it by subscribing to android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE and voilla, it works well. Thanks for the hints everybody